# Standalone Package: Convert Option + KOMA Script class

Tags: koma-script, standalone, convert

I'm trying to compile a `standalone` document using the option `class=scrartcl` for setting the KOMA script article class. In addition I use the `convert` option for generating an `.emf` file automatically:

```
\def\CONVERTCOMMAND{pdf2svg\space \infile\space \inname .svg%
\space &&%
\space inkscape\space -z%
\space -f\space \inname .svg%
\space --export-emf=\outfile%
\space && \space del\space \inname .svg %
}

\documentclass[11pt,
 class=scrartcl,
 convert={
    command={\noexpand\CONVERTCOMMAND},
    outext=.emf %damit Output erkannt wird
    }
]{standalone}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

This code throws a couple of `Undefined control sequence. \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}` errors when compiled with PDFLaTeX. No output files are produced.

As you can see, I use a more complex convert command, but the file compiles without errors when omitting the `class=scrartcl` option.

Also setting `class=scrartcl` and `convert=true` works fine, producing a PDF and a PNG file.

Based on these obsevations, I assume a conflict between the selected class and the custom convert command. Can you reproduce this error or is it specific for my system? Are there any possibilities to make these two options work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global options of `\documentclass` are not only interpreted by `standalone` but all classes and packages. So they also can be expanded several times. As long as the class and the packages do not process key-value options this is not a big problem. But KOMA-Script classes and several packages loaded by theses classes do process such options. So in this case `\CONVERTCOMMAND` is expanded by at least one of the packages while `\infile` is undefined.

To avoid this, you can use `\standaloneconfig` to add the `convert` option. But this has to be done either in `standalone.cfg` or at least before the conversion is done. Usually there is already a `standalone.cfg` that is loaded. But maybe you don't want to change it. The following solution uses `scrlfile` to add the `\standaloneconfig` command just after reading this configuration file. And for the case there is not any `standalone.cfg` it make one.

```
\def\CONVERTCOMMAND{pdf2svg \infile\space \inname .svg
&&
inkscape -z -f \inname .svg --export-emf=\outfile\space
&& del \inname .svg || rm \inname .svg%
}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
% If there is already a `standalone.cfg` we add one command.
\AfterFile{standalone.cfg}{%
  \standaloneconfig{%
    convert={
      command={\CONVERTCOMMAND},
      outext=.emf %damit Output erkannt wird
    }
  }
}
% If their isn't any `standalone.cfg` we make a dummy one.
\IfFileExists{standalone.cfg}{}{% works also with package filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{standalone.cfg}
\relax
\end{filecontents*}
}

\documentclass[11pt,
 class=scrartcl,
]{standalone}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

BTW: I've reduced the usage of not needed `\space` commands and added `rm` to remove the SVG-file if `del` fails. So this version works on my linux machine.

Here is a snapshot from the `log`-file:

> ```
> \sa@box=\box29
> runsystem(pdflatex  -shell-escape  -jobname 'test' '\expandafter\def\csname sa@
> internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{test}')...executed.
>
> \sa@read=\read1
> runsystem(pdf2svg test.pdf test.svg && inkscape -z -f test.svg --export-emf=tes
> t.emf && del test.svg || rm test.svg)...executed.
> ```

Comment: great, thanks for your very informative answer!